# ISPSS: Cross-sectional time series analysis

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, spss, panel-data

I am trying to run a multiple regression in SPSS.

I am using panel data with 4 independent variables. Of these, one is a dummy variable.

Can someone please guide me through the process or give me some hints since I'm a beginner in this.

I have 350 companies. These companies have a "score" (dependent variable) for 4 different years. There are 4 different independent variables (1 dummy) that are affecting the dependent variable.

When i go to Analyze - Mixed model - Linear, i don't know how to proceed. I don't know what to put as "subjects" and "repeated", and i don't know which variables should be used fixed. [image]

Comment: Did you try anything at all? Like Analyze > Regression > Linear??

Comment: Googling for "panel data SPSS" gives you lots of hits, for instance this one: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/library/gee.htm I suggest you work through some introductory material. If you have *specific* questions, we will be happy to try and help you. (But StackOverflow would be better for SPSS-related questions, CrossValidated aims at statistics, not programming.)

Comment: I made some edits to the text!

Answer (score 2):

It really depends of what you want to know regarding your data. Are you interested in growth of your dependent? changes over time? or just your baseline? Can you reshape your data, and analyse in a different framework from mixed models? I'm assuming you may need to stick to mixed models by some reason.

Lets say your dependent is y, your independents are i1-i4, and your cases are id and your time variable is year, you could fit a model with following syntax:

```
mixed y with year i1 i2 i3 i4 
/print=solution
/method=ml
/fixed=intercept year i4 year*i4
/random=intercept year i1 i2 i3 | subject(id) covtype(un).
```

However, the parameters would only make sense if you know what your fitting to the data in each model. You could check http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/examples/alda/ for different types of models for longitudinal data. That website has many examples from the Singer & Willet (2003) book on longitudinal analysis in different stat software (including r, stata, sas, spss, mplus, mlwin & hlm).

A main point to resolve is if you need to centred your covariates or not, and if you need to transformed your dependent or not. Most of the times, parameters are not directly interpretable and may required a variable transformation (e.g. log transformation, centering covariates). Centering variables is more tricky, because it really depends on what the covariate is. When is age, instead of mean centred, you can use a meaningful starting point (e.g age of entry, 14 years). In your case, I can't make any suggestions on that aspect, given I have no knowledge on what your covariates are.

Singer & Willet (2003) 'Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis' and the UCLA site with examples, are good reference to start.